# yii2 Image to have a label below the image

Tags: image, yii2, yii2-basic-app

In yii2 I am displaying images from the daabase and for the same images I have comments in the database table. I want the image description to be below the image, which i am not able to achieve.

My code.

```
<div class="margin-top-20">
  <h5>  <p class="details-edit">  <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> GHS Pictograms </p> </h5>
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-edit">
        <div class="panel-body">

            <?php 
             $images = '';
             $a = '';
              // append all images
             //  var_dump($data->getPictogramPath()); exit();
            foreach($model->getPictogramPath() as $name)       
                $images =$images.' '.Html::img(\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/web'.$name->pictogram_filepath,['alt'=>'','width'=>'100','height'=>'100', 'data-toggle'=>'tooltip','data-placement'=>'left','title' => $name->pictogram_comment ,'style'=>'cursor:default;']).Html::label($name->pictogram_comment,['class' => 'pictogram-label']);
                $a = $a.Html::label($name->pictogram_comment);

            echo ($images);
           ?>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My output is : [image: Click here]

I am not able to get the label below the image.. Can anyone sugggest me what is the issue here?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a little change on your html structure. First of all need **wrap each image and label in block**, also need make a **couple changes in your css** files.

You code will look like this:

```
$images = '';
$a = '';

// Append all images          
foreach($model->getPictogramPath() as $name) {
    $images .= Html::beginTag('div', ['class' => 'img-and-label-wrapper']);
    $images .= Html::img(\Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl. '/web' . $name->pictogram_filepath, ['alt' => '', 'width' => '100', 'height' => '100', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'left', 'title' => $name->pictogram_comment ,'style'=>'cursor:default;']);
    $images .= Html::label($name->pictogram_comment,['class' => 'pictogram-label']);
    $images .= Html::endTag('div');
}

echo $images;
```

Here styles that you need to add:

```
.img-and-label-wrapper {
  display : inline-block;
}

.img-and-label-wrapper label{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Guess this will helpful for you